# How do I package a mixed project solution with only one build step in VSTS?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, msbuild, azure-pipelines

I have an old ASP.Net app targeting the .NET Framework 4.7.  This app has been a five year development exercise and is very mature.  It has quite a few supporting library projects all in the same solution.  There are three EF6 projects for database communication.

We have started the move to .NET Core and have added a new .NET Core web project targeting .NET Framework 4.7 so we can use the EF6 projects while we migrate.  This is all working well.

Our source code is hosted in VSTS and we are using a remote build server in our domain instead of an Azure build server.  I can successfully build the solution without MSBuild Arguments.  But the MSBuild Arguments to produce the Deployment Package I need are different for the legacy ASP.Net app and the ASP.Net Core app.  So I have created two solutions, one that has the legacy project and all the library projects but not the ASP.Net Core project.  And another with the ASP.Net Core project and all the library projects but not the legacy ASP.Net project.  I also have two build steps, one for each solution which contains the MSBuild Arguments that each web project needs to build the Deployment Package.

I was wondering if anyone knows how to change this setup so that I only have one build step on the main solution.  Is there any VSTS Task that will take the output from the build and create the Deployment Packages I need?  I need web.config transforms on the legacy ASP.Net project, but that's not supported with .NET Core, so I think that's where the hang-up is.  I know there is a way to create an Azure deployment solution that uses DSC and powershell to package and deploy everything, but that seems like overkill to me.  I have included the two MSBuild setups below.

Legacy ASP.Net MSBuild Arguments:

> /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\App" /p:AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=False

ASP.Net Core MSBuild Arguments:

> /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\RSD.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"

Comment: You can't have a ".NET Core web project targeting .NET Framework 4.7". Did you mean ASP.NET Core?

Comment: The only solution I can think of makes it more ""complicated"" as in adding a custom MSBuild project file that takes care of the CI process, but allows for configuring the right settings on a per-branch basis so you don't have to reconfigure the CI every time you change your application structure. Is that an option for you? (similar to this [CI script](https://gist.github.com/dasMulli/69f5303aa79a8cd4060e44891c90fd2d))

Comment: I did in fact mean ASP.Net Core.  Sorry, I said ASP.Net Core in most places, but left out "ASP" in one of my references.

Comment: Do you solve this issue with my way?

Comment: @starain-MSFT, unfortunately I haven't been able to try yet.  I upgraded the .NET Core project to .NET Core 2.0 and have run into no end of troubles.  When I build the legacy .NET site I get one set of system dlls, but for some reason, when I compile the .NET Core project it replaces those system dlls in the legacy bin folder with older versions.  This causes bindingRedirect issues.  The files in question are System.Runtime and System.IO files with version 4.0.11.0.  They are being replaced by versions with number 4.0.10.0.  System.Http is also an issue, but it is ALWAYS an issue.

Comment: @starain-MSFT, would you be able to help with the dll replacement issue?  I can provide a BeyondCompare report of the files being replaced by the .NET Core build.

Comment: Could you provide the simple projects that can reproduce this issue? (Share it on the OneDrive)

Comment: Lat last night I was able to solve most of the issues.  We use DocumentFormal.OpenXml and the ClosedXML NuGet packages to generate Excel document.  The upgrade to v2.7.1 of DocumentFormat caused a TON of problems with references. To reproduce, create a new ASP.Net Web App (not Core) in VS2017 and then upgrade all packages. Add DocumentFormat.OpenXml and you'll see the problems immediately. Rolling back to v2.5 solves most issues. We still have exclamation marks by System.Net.Http and System.IO.COmpression, but everything works.

Comment: You may also need to add a reference to Microsoft.Owin.Security.Interop before adding the reference to DocumentFormat.OpenXml.

Answer (score 0):

You can create publish profile for each projects with the same name, then deploy projects with the profile by specify `/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=[profile name]`.

Note, you need to specify **relative path** of package location in publish profile. (e.g. ....\a\Web1.zip)

Comment: This sounds promising.  I'll give it a shot and check back with results.

Comment: @Brian Feel free to post the result here.

Comment: Ahh, I misunderstood what you were saying with this.  This would still require performing two separate builds.  I'd like to perform one build on the sln that contains all projects (asp.net v4 and asp.net core v2.0 targeting net47).  The take the results from that one build and deploy the asp.net v4 project to one website and the results of the asp.net core 2.0 project to a separate website.

Comment: @Brian No, you just need a Visual Studio Build task to build the solution directly. What's the problem when you to do it with my way? Can you post the detail log here?